# I would like to apply high mesh details such as wrinkles and pores. Should I apply to the base sculpt or to a lower poly retopology?

Tags: sculpting

[image]

If I'm to apply to a low poly, do I need to use the multiresolution modifier?

Comment: Have you considered baking a normal map so that you can keep your second object low-poly?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. But I was following some tutorials, and people used to do a low poly, then more sculpt in the low poly, using a multiresolution modifier, and then baking the normals to use on another low poly mesh. Kind of confusing

Comment: Yes, multires is very convenient to sculpt, and once you've finished you bake the result and you don't need the mutlires any more

Comment: watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0FwsMkWm0k

Comment: Understood! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could duplicate your object, sculpt on the copy with ***Dyntopo***, then bake the result on the original object.

Another method is to use the ***Multiresolution*** modifier then bake the result on the same object as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0FwsMkWm0k) by PIXXO 3D. It works fine with 2.79, not with my version of 2.8 but it may have improved since.

- Subdivide your object a bit. *Shade Smooth* it. Unwrap it (*Smart UV Project* for example).

[image]

- Give it a *Multiresolution* modifier, click *Subdivide* 2 or 3 times, sculpt the object.

[image]

- Create a blank picture, prepare your node setup, make sure that the Image Texture is set to *Non-Color Data*.

[image]

- Bake the normals.

[image]

- Deactivate the *Multires* modifier. Check the result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm going with the mutiresolution method. Saw a tutorial by Grant Abbit, in which he also follow this process